# Bootstrap dropdown navigation jumping on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, drop-down-menu

I am working on http://www.disccaddie.com/. Everything seems to be working well, except that on iOS (and presumably other mobile devices) the Bootstrap navbar is jumping or stuttering when you press the hamburger icon. I've tried several solutions, but can't seem to fix it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, when you click the hamburger, it will expand the menu down, then quickly jump back up, and then snap open.

Comment: Found a solution yet? I have this issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that it was caused by applying a transition on all elements in my css.

I note you have the following in your stylesheet:

```
* {
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out; }
```

I think if you apply this more specifically to the elements you'd like to animate, or at least override it on your nav elements, it should solve the problem.